# NullPointerException in compareTo on saving modified entity with ManyToOne relationship

Tags: spring-data-jpa

**Summary** (code below)

I have an entity ProcessInstance with a ManyToOne relationship with an entity ExpectedBusinessTimestamp. In a controller, I load a ProcessInstance (incl. ExpectedBusinessTimestamp), modify a field and then save the ProcessInstance.

The save operation fails with a NullPointerException in the compareTo-method of the ExpectedBusinessTimestamp, because the left object (the *this* object in the compareTo) hasn't been loaded properly. The *this* object isn't null, but only its ID is filled in, all other fields are null.

I'm thinking that for some reason, during the save, the ProcessInstance is reloaded from the database but for some reason doesn't load the ExpectedBusinessTimestamp with it, even if the FetchType is explicitly set to EAGER. When the save operation then compares the stored ProcessInstance with the one in memory, at some point, the ExpectedBusinessTimestamps are compared, but the one from the database isn't loaded, leading to a NullPointerException.

**Code: ProcessInstance**

```
@Entity
public class ProcessInstance{

    @ManyToOne
    private ExpectedBusinessTimestamp expectedBusinessTimestamp;
    public ExpectedBusinessTimestamp getExpectedBusinessTimestamp() {
        return expectedBusinessTimestamp;
    }
    public void setExpectedBusinessTimestamp(ExpectedBusinessTimestamp expectedBusinessTimestamp){
        this.expectedBusinessTimestamp = expectedBusinessTimestamp;
    }
}
```

**Code: ExpectedBusinessTimestamp**

```
@Entity
public class ExpectedBusinessTimestamp {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "expectedBusinessTimestamp")
    List<ProcessInstance> processInstances;
    public List<ProcessInstance> getProcessInstances(){ return processInstances; }
}
```

**Code: Controller**

```
ProcessInstance previousInstance = processInstanceRepository.findPrevious(
                processDefinition, expectedBusinessTimestamp);
previousInstance.setLatestVersion(false);
processInstanceRepository.save(previousInstance);
```

**More detail**

The code classes are of course a bit more complex than shown, but I didn't want to paste all the code here. If something relevant is missing, please let me know.

Debugging has allowed me to confirm:

- The repository is AutoWired in.
- The previousInstance is loaded (including its ExpectedBusinessTimestamp)
- On saving, an entity is loaded from the database (this is deep in the call stack, spring jpa hibernate etc, not my code).
- On saving, the compareTo of the ExpectedBusinessTimestamp is repeatedly called. In one of these occasions, the ExpectedBusinessTimestamp only has its Id filled in, all other fields are null. A NullPointerException is thrown when these fields are compared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the issue was yet another entity, which has a OneToMany relationship with the ExpectedBusinessTimestamp as SortedSet and annotated with @SortNatural. The SortedSet enforces the use of the Comparable-interface, which is why there was a compareTo method in the ExpectedBusinessTimestamp class in the first place.

Changing the SortedSet to a List and using @OrderBy annotation instead of @SortNatural has solved all issues.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "expectedBusinessTimestampTemplate", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@OrderBy("date asc, time asc")
private List<ExpectedBusinessTimestamp> expectedBusinessTimestamps;
```